# VirtualBox Port Forwarding Not Working

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, router

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 Host running VirtualBox with a Guest Ubuntu Server 10.04 set up.

My host machine is behind a linksys router. I would like to use the VM as a web server (to the outside world). I have NAT networking between the host and guest machines, and used port forwarding ([guide here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward)) to foward port 8888 on the host to port 80 on the guest.

I also have my linksys router forwarding port 8888 to my host's IP address.

Now when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8888 in a browser on the host, I get the expected web page served from the guest.

But if I try to navigate to http://w.x.y.z:8888 (where w.x.y.z is my router's IP to the outside world), I get a page timeout.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*/facepalm*

turns out port forwarding works much better when you don't make silly typos.